# 'Class' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Tags: c#

I'm coding an application which uses a fingerprint reader to capture images of someone's fingerprints and save it in the database.

I'm busy converting vb logic into c#, but I'm stuck here...

Within my main form I have 2 classes: fingerPrints and fingerImage respectively.

My issue is the following:

From my fingerPrints class, I needed to reference the fingerImage class.  Here's some code for clarity:

This method is derived from the fingerPrint class, which references the fingerImage class:

```
public byte[] getImageFromFinger(string finger)
        {
            foreach (fingerImage fi in fingerImage)
            {
                if (fi.Finger == finger)
                    return fi.Image;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

My problem is the error which I can't seem to fix...fingerImage is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'.

I need to loop through the class 10 times, once for each finger, but I'm doing something wrong and I think it's something small.   Any help would be appreciated.

Furthermore, here's some code from my fingerImage class, just in case...

```
public class fingerImage : frmFingerprintsMain
        {
            private byte[] _image;
            private string _finger;

            public fingerImage(byte[] image, string finger)
            {
                Image = image;
                Finger = finger;
            }

            public byte[] Image
            {
                get { return _image; }
                set { _image = value; }
            }

            public string Finger
            {
                get { return _finger; }
                set { _finger = value; }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You will also need to implement `IEnumerable<TypeYouWantToIterateOver>` in order to `foreach` over an instance of your type. But in your case it looks more like you want to iterate over a list of `fingerImage` than an actual instance of a fingerImage.

Comment: I would suggest you follow the naming convention rules for .NET to avoid confusion. Pascal naming for classes / members and Camel casing for variable names. Check [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: You don't loop through classes. You loop through collections of objects which are themselves objects. You need to learn the difference between 'class' and 'object'. When you do, it will become obvious why you are getting that error.

Comment: I had the same idea...about it not being a collection or an object.  it's just the way it's written in vb.net...it looks like a standard class instead of being an object or a collection.  since I don't really work with such things every day, it really didn't make sense...

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the error because you have no variable named `fingerImage`. You do however have a type called `fingerImage`.

You probably need to get a collection of `fingerImage`s from somewhere to iterate through.

Answer (score 3):

A class is a *type*; you seem to be thinking of the word "class" as synonymous with "object" (you can't "loop through" a *class*; you can loop through an enumerable *object*, though).

Basically, what you need instead of this:

```
foreach (fingerImage fi in fingerImage)
```

...is something like this:

```
foreach (fingerImage fi in fingerImages)
```

...where `fingerImages` is an *collection* of *instances* of the `fingerImage` class.

Where exactly that collection is, I can't really say without seeing more code. But I'm assuming you have one somewhere (maybe a `fingerImage[]`? Or a `List<fingerImage>`?).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach (FingerImage fi in fingerImages)
{
    ....
}
```

Note that:

- The variable name that you are iterating over is probably some sort of collection and the variable name is probably plural (and if it isn't, it most likely should be).
- The class should be in Pascal case to follow the [Microsoft naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx). It looks like you need to fix your class definition too. Following the naming conventions can reduce confusion and make errors like this easier to spot.

I know that following naming conventions often seems like unnecessary work, but it will save you time in the long run, and especially when you have other people join your team.

Answer (score 2):

**fingerImage** fi in **fingerImage**

These two types are the same, this shouldn't happen. The latter fingerImage, should be a collection.